# script is running fine, but there's nothing on the canvas

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, html5-canvas

I'm attempting to write one of the [Dart](http://dartlang.org/) demos in Javascript/Coffeescript. Everything seems to be working just fine as far as the code goes, but nothing ever appears on the canvas.  I've tested this in Firefox and Chrome and I'm not getting any console errors or anything.  I can't quite figure this one out.  Any ideas why my canvas stays blank?

Here's my code at http://jsbin.com/orazag/1/edit

And for posterity, here it is, too.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
     for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
     BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file. -->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Solar System Demo</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="solar.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Solar System</h1>

    <p>A solar system visualization using requestAnimationFrame.</p>

    <div>
      <canvas id="container" width="500px" height="400px"></canvas>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <p id="summary"> </p>
      <p id="notes"> </p>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="solar.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file */
/* for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a */
/* BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file. */

body {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 15px;
}

p {
  color: #333;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#summary {
  float: left;
}

#notes {
  float: right;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: right;
}

.error {
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
}
```

Coffeescript:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame

main = ->
   solarSystem = new SolarSystem document.getElementById 'container'
   solarSystem.start()
   return

fpsAverage = null
showFps = (fps) ->
   fpsAverage ?= fps
   fpsAverage = fps * 0.05 + fpsAverage * 0.95
   document.getElementById('notes').textContent = Math.round(fpsAverage) + ' fps'
   return

class Point
    constructor: (@x, @y) ->

class SolarSystem
    constructor: (@canvas) ->
        @renderTime = null
    start: ->
        @width = @canvas.parentNode.clientWidth
        @height = @canvas.parentNode.clientHeight
        @canvas.width = @width
        @_start()
        return
    _start: ->
        # Create the Sun.
        @sun = new PlanetaryBody @, 'Sun', '#ff2', 14.0
        # Add planets.
        @sun.addPlanet new PlanetaryBody @, 'Mercury', 'orange', 0.382, 0.387, 0.241
        @sun.addPlanet new PlanetaryBody @, 'Venus', 'green', 0.949, 0.723, 0.615

        earth = new PlanetaryBody @, 'Earth', '#33f', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
        @sun.addPlanet earth
        earth.addPlanet new PlanetaryBody @, 'Moon', 'gray', 0.2, 0.14, 0.075

        @sun.addPlanet new PlanetaryBody @, 'Mars', 'red', 0.532, 1.524, 1.88
        @addAsteroidBelt @sun, 150

        f = 0.1
        h = 1 / 1500.0
        g = 1 / 72.0

        jupiter = new PlanetaryBody @, 'Jupiter', 'gray', 4.0, 5.203, 11.86
        @sun.addPlanet jupiter
        jupiter.addPlanet new PlanetaryBody @, 'Io', 'gray', 3.6 * f, 421 * h, 1.769 * g
        jupiter.addPlanet new PlanetaryBody @, 'Europa', 'gray', 3.1 * f, 671 * h, 3.551 * g
        jupiter.addPlanet new PlanetaryBody @, 'Ganymede', 'gray', 5.3 * f, 1070 * h, 7.154 * g
        jupiter.addPlanet new PlanetaryBody @, 'Callisto', 'gray', 4.8 * f, 1882 * h, 16.689 * g

        @requestRedraw()
        return
    draw: ->
        @requestRedraw()
        time = Date.now()
        if @renderTime?
            showFps Math.round 1000 / (time - @renderTime)
        @renderTime = time
        context = @canvas.getContext '2d'
        @drawBackground context
        @drawPlanets context
        return
    drawBackground: (context) ->
        context.fillStyle = 'white'
        context.rect 0, 0, @width, @height
        context.fill()
        return
    drawPlanets: (context) ->
        @sun.draw context, @width / 2, @height /2
        return
    requestRedraw: ->
        window.requestAnimationFrame => @draw()
        return
    addAsteroidBelt: (body, count) ->
        # Asteroids are generally between 2.06 and 3.27 AUs.
        for [0...count]
            radius = 2.06 + Math.random() * (3.27 - 2.06)
            body.addPlanet new PlanetaryBody @, 'asteroid', '#777', 0.1 * Math.random(), radius, radius * 2
        return
    normalizeOrbitRadius: (r) ->
        r * (@width / 10.0)
    normalizePlanetSize: (r) ->
        Math.log(r + 1) * (@width / 100.0)

class PlanetaryBody
    constructor: (@solarSystem, @name, @color, bodySize, orbitRadius = 0.0, @orbitPeriod = 0.0) ->
        @bodySize = solarSystem.normalizePlanetSize bodySize
        @orbitRadius = solarSystem.normalizeOrbitRadius orbitRadius
        @orbitSpeed = @_calculateSpeed orbitPeriod
        @planets = []
    addPlanet: (planet) ->
        @planets.push planet
    draw: (context, x, y) ->
        pos = @_calculatePos x, y
        @drawSelf context, pos.x, pos.y
        @drawChildren context, pos.x, pos.y
        return
    drawSelf: (context, x, y) ->
        context.save()
        try
            context.lineWidth = 0.5
            context.fillStyle = @color
            context.strokeStyle = @color
            if @bodySize >= 2.0
                context.shadowOffsetX = 2
                context.shadowOffsetY = 2
                context.shadowBlur = 2
                context.shadowColor = '#ddd'

            context.beginPath()
            context.arc x, y, @bodySize, 0, Math.PI * 2, false
            context.fill()
            context.closePath()
            context.stroke()

            context.shadowOffsetX = 0
            context.shadowOffsetY = 0
            context.shadowBlur = 0

            context.beginPath()
            context.arc x, y, @bodySize, 0, Math.PI * 2, false
            context.fill()
            context.closePath()
            context.stroke()
        finally
           context.restore()
        return
    drawChildren: (context, x, y) ->
        for planet in @planets
            planet.draw context, x, y
        return
    _calculateSpeed: (period) ->
        if period == 0.0
            0.0
        else
            1 / (60.0 * 24.0 * 2 * period)
    _calculatePos: (x, y) ->
        if @orbitSpeed == 0.0
            new Point x, y
        else
            angle = @solarSystem.renderTime * @orbitSpeed
            new Point @orbitRadius * Math.cos(angle) + x, @orbitRadius * Math.sin(angle) + y

window.onload = main
```

Or, if you prefer, here's the equivalent Javascript:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
(function() {
  var PlanetaryBody, Point, SolarSystem, fpsAverage, main, showFps;

  window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

  main = function() {
    var solarSystem;
    solarSystem = new SolarSystem(document.getElementById('container'));
    solarSystem.start();
  };

  fpsAverage = null;

  showFps = function(fps) {
    if (fpsAverage == null) {
      fpsAverage = fps;
    }
    fpsAverage = fps * 0.05 + fpsAverage * 0.95;
    document.getElementById('notes').textContent = Math.round(fpsAverage) + ' fps';
  };

  Point = (function() {

    function Point(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    return Point;

  })();

  SolarSystem = (function() {

    function SolarSystem(canvas) {
      this.canvas = canvas;
      this.renderTime = null;
    }

    SolarSystem.prototype.start = function() {
      this.width = this.canvas.parentNode.clientWidth;
      this.height = this.canvas.parentNode.clientHeight;
      this.canvas.width = this.width;
      this._start();
    };

    SolarSystem.prototype._start = function() {
      var earth, f, g, h, jupiter;
      this.sun = new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Sun', '#ff2', 14.0);
      this.sun.addPlanet(new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Mercury', 'orange', 0.382, 0.387, 0.241));
      this.sun.addPlanet(new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Venus', 'green', 0.949, 0.723, 0.615));
      earth = new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Earth', '#33f', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      this.sun.addPlanet(earth);
      earth.addPlanet(new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Moon', 'gray', 0.2, 0.14, 0.075));
      this.sun.addPlanet(new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Mars', 'red', 0.532, 1.524, 1.88));
      this.addAsteroidBelt(this.sun, 150);
      f = 0.1;
      h = 1 / 1500.0;
      g = 1 / 72.0;
      jupiter = new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Jupiter', 'gray', 4.0, 5.203, 11.86);
      this.sun.addPlanet(jupiter);
      jupiter.addPlanet(new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Io', 'gray', 3.6 * f, 421 * h, 1.769 * g));
      jupiter.addPlanet(new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Europa', 'gray', 3.1 * f, 671 * h, 3.551 * g));
      jupiter.addPlanet(new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Ganymede', 'gray', 5.3 * f, 1070 * h, 7.154 * g));
      jupiter.addPlanet(new PlanetaryBody(this, 'Callisto', 'gray', 4.8 * f, 1882 * h, 16.689 * g));
      this.requestRedraw();
    };

    SolarSystem.prototype.draw = function() {
      var context, time;
      this.requestRedraw();
      time = Date.now();
      if (this.renderTime != null) {
        showFps(Math.round(1000 / (time - this.renderTime)));
      }
      this.renderTime = time;
      context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
      this.drawBackground(context);
      this.drawPlanets(context);
    };

    SolarSystem.prototype.drawBackground = function(context) {
      context.fillStyle = 'white';
      context.rect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
      context.fill();
    };

    SolarSystem.prototype.drawPlanets = function(context) {
      this.sun.draw(context, this.width / 2, this.height / 2);
    };

    SolarSystem.prototype.requestRedraw = function() {
      var _this = this;
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        return _this.draw();
      });
    };

    SolarSystem.prototype.addAsteroidBelt = function(body, count) {
      var radius, _i;
      for (_i = 0; 0 <= count ? _i < count : _i > count; 0 <= count ? _i++ : _i--) {
        radius = 2.06 + Math.random() * (3.27 - 2.06);
        body.addPlanet(new PlanetaryBody(this, 'asteroid', '#777', 0.1 * Math.random(), radius, radius * 2));
      }
    };

    SolarSystem.prototype.normalizeOrbitRadius = function(r) {
      return r * (this.width / 10.0);
    };

    SolarSystem.prototype.normalizePlanetSize = function(r) {
      return Math.log(r + 1) * (this.width / 100.0);
    };

    return SolarSystem;

  })();

  PlanetaryBody = (function() {

    function PlanetaryBody(solarSystem, name, color, bodySize, orbitRadius, orbitPeriod) {
      this.solarSystem = solarSystem;
      this.name = name;
      this.color = color;
      if (orbitRadius == null) {
        orbitRadius = 0.0;
      }
      this.orbitPeriod = orbitPeriod != null ? orbitPeriod : 0.0;
      this.bodySize = solarSystem.normalizePlanetSize(bodySize);
      this.orbitRadius = solarSystem.normalizeOrbitRadius(orbitRadius);
      this.orbitSpeed = this._calculateSpeed(orbitPeriod);
      this.planets = [];
    }

    PlanetaryBody.prototype.addPlanet = function(planet) {
      return this.planets.push(planet);
    };

    PlanetaryBody.prototype.draw = function(context, x, y) {
      var pos;
      pos = this._calculatePos(x, y);
      this.drawSelf(context, pos.x, pos.y);
      this.drawChildren(context, pos.x, pos.y);
    };

    PlanetaryBody.prototype.drawSelf = function(context, x, y) {
      context.save();
      try {
        context.lineWidth = 0.5;
        context.fillStyle = this.color;
        context.strokeStyle = this.color;
        if (this.bodySize >= 2.0) {
          context.shadowOffsetX = 2;
          context.shadowOffsetY = 2;
          context.shadowBlur = 2;
          context.shadowColor = '#ddd';
        }
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, this.bodySize, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
        context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
        context.shadowBlur = 0;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, this.bodySize, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
      } finally {
        context.restore();
      }
    };

    PlanetaryBody.prototype.drawChildren = function(context, x, y) {
      var planet, _i, _len, _ref;
      _ref = this.planets;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        planet = _ref[_i];
        planet.draw(context, x, y);
      }
    };

    PlanetaryBody.prototype._calculateSpeed = function(period) {
      if (period === 0.0) {
        return 0.0;
      } else {
        return 1 / (60.0 * 24.0 * 2 * period);
      }
    };

    PlanetaryBody.prototype._calculatePos = function(x, y) {
      var angle;
      if (this.orbitSpeed === 0.0) {
        return new Point(x, y);
      } else {
        angle = this.solarSystem.renderTime * this.orbitSpeed;
        return new Point(this.orbitRadius * Math.cos(angle) + x, this.orbitRadius * Math.sin(angle) + y);
      }
    };

    return PlanetaryBody;

  })();

  window.onload = main;

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My basic debugging process here was:

1. Are the draw functions being called? `console.log('drawing')` in the draw function told me, yes they are.
2. Are the draw function being sent proper values? `console.log(x, y)` in the draw function told me both were `NaN`.

So with some `console.log`'s sprinkled around I found that the X and Y being sent to your draw functions were `NaN`. So somewhere your doing some bad math.  I traced it back to the `_calculateSpeed` method in the constructor where you passed in `orbitPeriod` but the construct accepts that as `@orbitPeriod`, which of course is a totally different thing.

```
class PlanetaryBody
    constructor: (@solarSystem, @name, @color, bodySize, orbitRadius = 0.0, @orbitPeriod = 0.0) ->
        @bodySize = solarSystem.normalizePlanetSize bodySize
        @orbitRadius = solarSystem.normalizeOrbitRadius orbitRadius

        # This line right here:
        @orbitSpeed = @_calculateSpeed orbitPeriod

        # Should be this instead!
        @orbitSpeed = @_calculateSpeed @orbitPeriod

        @planets = []
```

`console.log` is your friend, add it where you think your data is messed up to debug like a pro.

Comment: Thanks for the added info.  Also, how embarrassing! It came down to a single character typo.

Comment: In my experiencing some of the most baffling, prolific bugs that test your sanity usually come down to something trivial. Don't be too hard on yourself. :)